# How can I fix the boot that broke after trying to uninstall ubuntu?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, usb, boot-repair

My Lenovo Ideapad 330-15ICH won't boot. [This](https://youtu.be/3Z5KI3IdQvE) is the error I get and [here](https://prnt.sc/mdg43p) is a closer look.

I've tried both legacy mode and UEFI but it's still the same. I've tried also setting fastboot and secure boot enabled and disabled. [Here](https://prnt.sc/mdgitz) is how my boot section from BIOS looks like.

The other thing I've tried was to format a USB stick with Windows 10 so that I can boot from it and run some commands that I've seen in a tutorial. The problem is that when I insert the USB stick, I still get the error from above, the only difference being that the Lenovo logo stays stuck for ~1 minute.

How did I get in this situation?
I had dual boot (Windows 10 and Ubuntu) but the grub didn't appeared on boot, so I booted into Windows and deleted the Ubuntu volumes and extended the main one. Then  I've tried inserting another Linux USB installer but I had a cmd-like screen that said something about grub error. I booted back to Windows and tried to completely uninstall Ubuntu with a tool called EasyBCD through a tutorial. Now here I am.

I have my BIOS updated from Lenovo drivers if that matters.

EDIT: When I follow the instructions of the error, nothing changes. I still get the same error after reboot.
As for inserting a Ubuntu USB, it boots to a terminal about grub rescue. I've tries to rescue the grub by following [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J4uK3Nf1g2U) tutorial, but it didn't worked. I did the tutorial right.

Comment: Just do what the text suggest .. boot on your Windows install media and repair. Or reinstall Ubuntu from Live media.

Comment: I did both but without success.

Comment: You aren't booting from the Ubuntu USB or you need to burn it again. Anyway that unlikely to recover Windows

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia How can I tell I am booting from Ubuntu USB or not? When I plug the USB, i get the grub rescue error and when I leave it out, I get the first error. As for burning it again, I've burnt it 2 times without success.

Comment: You need to open UEFI settings or use the boot override menu to make sure the USB installation media (Windows or Ubuntu) is selected. And *EasyBCD through a tutorial* not applicable is what broke Windows. EasyBCD cannot be used in a UEFI installation!!! And now you need to boot a Windows 10 USB in UEFI mode and repair bootloader or something. But Windows is off topic here.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia I don't have a override menu. Here are all my options: Here is a video with all my options:
https://imgur.com/6E73Kfs. I can's see a list with all the storage devices (no hdd, no usb). When I put my USB in, even if it's UEFI or legacy, I still get the initial error.

Answer (score 0):

What's happened is that your Windows installation is now being used as the boot partition, but it's confused because the partition layout/order on the disk has been changed.

Your basic options are:

- Do as the error suggests and insert a Windows installation media which will repair the bootloader in Windows and fix the issue.
- Insert a Ubuntu Live CD and install it again which will restore the GRUB boot loader, which will see you have Windows installed and create an entry for it in the menu.

If you wish to remove the Ubuntu partitions later you can do this but you must a.) ensure they are near the end of the disk and b.) ensure that before you shutdown Windows you run `bootsect.exe` to update the boot record.

Comment: Both ways do not work for me.

Comment: @PaulMihali If booting Windows follow the instructions on your screenshot. What happens? If booting Ubuntu, how come reinstalling it didn't work? What happens now? Either way please [edit] the question with that update so the the answer can be improved if Kristopher feels like it. Suggestion: Disable Lergacy support; UEFI only. It makes life and dual-booting so much easier.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia I just updated the post.